# If $p=a^2+4b^2$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $a$ is quadratic residu modulo $p$?

Tags: number-theory, legendre-symbol

If $p=a^2+4b^2$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ prime, then $a$ is quadratic residu modulo $p$?

Approach: I thought it was true. (I could't find a counterexample). So I tried to prove it. I deduced that $a$ is a quadratic residu modulo $p$ iff $b$ is. Second I deduced that $p\equiv 1 \mod 4$ and that $a$ is odd. Can someone give me a hint on how to finish the proof? Thanks.

Comment: The concept of odd numbers do not exist modulo $p$ (unless $p = 2$), so the fact that $a$ is odd probably has no bearing on whether it's a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

Comment: Use reciprocity:clearly $p$ is a square modulo $a$.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Many thanks! You have the same reasoning as Paolo Leonetti in the answer below.

Comment: Are you asking only about $p$ prime?  The Question would be better with this made explicit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $p=a^2+4b^2$ then $p\equiv 1\bmod{4}$ hence
$$
\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{a}\right)=\left(\frac{p-a^2}{a}\right)=\left(\frac{(2b)^2}{a}\right)=1.
$$

Comment: Yes yes!!! Many thanks!

Comment: +1 Good job! You beat me to it, because I spent a few minutes thinking about how to do this without Jacobi symbols - largely because I don't remember Jacobi stuff in detail, so I had no choice :-)

Answer (score 8):

We easily see that $p\equiv1\pmod4$, so for any prime factor $q\mid a$ we have, by quadratic reciprocity
$$
\left(\frac pq\right)=\left(\frac qp\right).
$$
OTOH we have $a^2=p-4b^2$. Therefore
$$
p\equiv 4b^2=(2b)^2\pmod q
$$
and $\left(\dfrac pq\right)=1$ for all those primes $q$.

So all the prime factors of $a$ are QRs modulo $p$. Therefore so is $a$.

Comment: I'm working on the same problem and I researched and found your solution, which in approach is the most similar to the way I went about trying to solve this problem.  Could we discuss my attempt at a solution in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12070/number-theory)?